# Setting Customized ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity

I'm a new android developer and I need help in my problem.
My android application runs on min API 15.
I want to use `setSupportActionBar()` like:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

but it is not supported in API 15 and the activities in my application extend `AppCompatActivity` which doesn't have setSupportActionBar()

so how can I add my customized `ActionBar`??

my java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[] = {"Home", "Events"};
int Numboftabs = 2;
Tab1 t1;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
    t1 = adapter.getTab1();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(t);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.example.mshouman.gpdemo.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

my XML toolbar code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="5dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It should worked

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

because this is in support library

#### Try Cleaning your project

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work with **AppCompatActivity** @N J

Comment: add latest  support library in `build.gradle`

Comment: I have this exception:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mshouman.gpdemo/com.example.mshouman.gpdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Class is not a View android.support.v7.app.ActionBar**

at this line:
**        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  **

Comment: have you declared **Base.Theme.AppCompa.XXXXXX** theme as base theme

Comment: my application theme extends from **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**

Comment: I don't know where is the problem